# Fit method of gensim.sklearn_api.w2vmodel.W2VTransformer throws error when inputed 2-dimensional array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.6, word2vec, gensim

i'm trying to cluster some documents with word2vec and numpy.

`w2v = W2VTransformer()
X_train = w2v.fit_transform(X_train)`

When I run the fit or fit_transform I get this error:

> Exception in thread Thread-8:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\lperona\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users\lperona\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\lperona\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 99, in _worker_loop
>       tally, raw_tally = self._do_train_job(data_iterable, job_parameters, thread_private_mem)
>     File "C:\Users\lperona\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 539, in _do_train_job
>       tally += train_batch_cbow(self, sentences, alpha, work, neu1, self.compute_loss)
>     File "gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx", line 458, in gensim.models.word2vec_inner.train_batch_cbow
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

(X_train is a 2D numpy array of strings)

Does anyone know a solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gensim's word2vec has some problems when working with numpy arrays. Converting data to python lists helped me.